# Erro realm 'node:fs'

Tags: javascript, node.js, react, realmdb

Estou implementando uma progress bar na minha aplicação local, e estou usando realm DB como banco local, só que estou enfrentando o seguinte erro.

**./node_modules/realm/dist/bundle.node.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'node:fs' in 'C:\AdSoft\code\golerp-pdv-app\node_modules\realm\dist'**

Não sei o que está acontecendo pois nunca trabalhei com banco local ou realm, assim está o meu componente.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { LinearProgress, Typography, Box } from '@mui/material';
const Realm = require('realm');

const ProgressBar = () => {
  const realm = Realm.open(config)

  async function progressNotification(transferred, transferable) {
    const percentage = (transferred/transferable) * 100;

    console.log("TRANSFERIDO => ", `${percentage}%`)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const syncSession = realm.syncSession

    if(!syncSession) return

    syncSession.addProgressNotification(
        Realm.ProgressDirection.Download,
        Realm.ProgressMode.ReportIndefinitely,
        progressNotification
    )

    return () => {
        syncSession.removeProgressNotification(progressNotification)
    }
  },[])
  
  return (
    <>
      {percentage > 0 && percentage < 100 && (
        <Box sx={{ width: '100%', mr: 1 }}>
          <LinearProgress variant="determinate" value={percentage} />
        </Box>
      )}

      {percentage === 100 && (
        <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
          Sincronização completa
        </Typography>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default ProgressBar;
```